# Regexp: Removing escape characters from JSON string

Tags: regex, json

I get a JSON string that contains another JSON string in one data field, escaped with \ and surrounded by " ". I like to remove these before I parse them. I use regexp replace:

```
var data = evt.data.replace(/\\\"/g,"\"");
data = data.replace(/\"\{/g,"{");
data = data.replace(/\}\"/g,"}");
```

The input string:

```
{"data":[{"beehive":"yaylaswiese","gamestate":"{\"currentGame\":\"StorieS3\"}","magicspell":"","sid":"40cc9dba822746fd572cece0416b320426759cc8"}],"sid":"login"}
```

should be:

```
{"data":[{"beehive":"yaylaswiese","gamestate":{"currentGame":"StorieS3"},"magicspell":"","sid":"40cc9dba822746fd572cece0416b320426759cc8"}],"sid":"login"}
```

I works, but it looks very complicated to replace \" with ", "{ with { and }" with }

Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: Please post a sample of the input string. It seems like you should be able to parse the outer string, then target the element containing the inner one and separately parse that one.

Comment: How do you get this string? The inner one should be parseable, assuming the whole thing was loaded in an object `JSON.parse(obj.data[0].gamestate)`

Comment: Yes, maybe that's better. Also effects only the object ...

Comment: Does that actually work for you the way you have the object? That outer string as a JSON _string_ rather than a JS object won't parse with `JSON.parse()`.  If that works as suggested, I'll post an answer.

Comment: It actually works. I do it, like you suggested.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to perform any string replacements to unescape the inner string.  Instead, you can load the outer string into a variable and target the inner one by array keys or properties.  When found, you can `JSON.parse()` the inner one:

```
// Storing the main string in a variable
var outer = {"data":[{"beehive":"yaylaswiese","gamestate":"{\"currentGame\":\"StorieS3\"}","magicspell":"","sid":"40cc9dba822746fd572cece0416b320426759cc8"}],"sid":"login"};

// The inner string is accessible at
var inner = outer.data[0].gamestate;
// "{"currentGame":"StorieS3"}"

// Parse it:
JSON.parse(inner);
// Object {currentGame: "StorieS3"}
```